# Better approach for running background python script in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to Django and need some guidance

I am looking for something in Django that allows me to run background tasks while my website continues to work, and probably I can check for the status of the task.

So basically I am working on a recon engine. This engine will run other python scripts and displays the results in a nice and fancy way. The python scripts and other tools have been already developed by other people. My website's job is to run those python & shell scripts and save the result back to the database. These tools will take a considerable amount of time to gather the result.

So, what is the best approach for this? I looked for celery and Django Q, looks like it's an overkill for my small task. There's a lot of setup for Celery and Django, though I am open to learning new things, for a simple task to run something in the background, I don't wish to use something that is really complex.

Can you all please suggest what could be a better approach for doing something in background, and once the task is done, probably notify back to the Django and gather the result, or when task is running, I have an option to check the task's status, finished, killed or still running.

Answer (score 1):

Celery is, afaik, the most common method to achieve this in the django ecosystem. A simpler and more hacky method would be to use the multiprocessing module to spawn off background tasks. This can work fine if the workload is confined to a single machine. As soon as you need a second machine you'll be back to looking at task/job queues and distributed flows :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You don't need other broker (mq, redis etc...).

Or you can just run some crontab or scheduled job in OS layer, and store the result in the same storage like database or simply store in static file (json, csv etc...).

[Apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html)

This is a well scheduler package in python you can use.

But if you want to monitor the task status in background, you need to use celery or other powerful async worker. There are some package to monitoring your task like [django-celery-monitor](https://django-celery-monitor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you want to handle this simply, just write a file with status while task is running, and let django to get that file to know what status now.